# Problema con envío de datos via Ajax a un archivo php

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy recibiendo un NULL en mi archivo php el cual tendría que recibir el envío de datos sacados del LocalStorage vía Ajax.

Del Localstorage estoy extrayendo asi:

```
var calendarioAlmacenado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cactual'));
var registros = [];
registros.push(calendarioAlmacenado); 
console.log("DESDE LOCAL STORAGE",registros);
```

los datos están viniendo en un objeto asi

```
{d1: "lunes", d2: "martes", d3: "miercoles", d4: "jueves", d5: "viernes"}
```

A continuación trato de enviar registros a un archivo php de ésta manera:

```
var arraycalendario = new FormData(); 
arraycalendario.append("datoscalendario",registros);
const url = base_url + "/diasDisponiblesAjax/ajaxEditarCategoria";

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.open("POST", url);
   request.send(arraycalendario);
   http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      var objeto = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    }
    console.log(objeto);
      }
```

en mi php los recibo dentro de un método de ésta manera:

```
  public function ajaxEditarCategoria()
  {
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
      $data = json_decode($_POST['datoscalendario']);
     
      var_dump($data);
    }  

  }
```

y solo recibo un NULL no se si el FormData está enviando datos vacíos al php o si el php lo está
recibiendo de forma incorrecta. He tratado con ajax de jQuery y revisando el inspector en Network me dice NULL.

Quiero recibir el array para iterarlo en foreach. He cambiado también la forma de recibirlo en php
pero siempre comprobando que un post ha llegado y no hay caso.Creo que está enviando datos vacíos pero no se en qué me estoy equivocando si en el envío al la hora de formar el FormData o en el php me está faltando algo. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Utiliza `fetch` te hace las cosas más fáciles

Comment: Christian Gracias

Answer (score 1):

He descubierto el Problema Gracias a todos igualmente. El problema era que me faltó codificar el json asi que todo el codigo en JS quedó así:

```
var calendarioAlmacenado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cactual'));
var registros = [];
  registros.push(calendarioAlmacenado); 
    console.log("DESDE LOCAL STORAGE",registros);
var calcodif = JSON.stringify(registros); 

var arraycalendario = new FormData();

 arraycalendario.append("datoscalendario",calcodif);

const url = base_url + "/diasDisponiblesAjax/ajaxEditarCategoria";
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("POST", url);
   request.send(arraycalendario);
   http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      var objeto = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    }
    console.log(objeto);
     }
```